# Go Tour #5: select statement example

Tags: go, concurrency

I'm new to the Go language and am currently going through the Go tour. I have a question regarding the [concurrency example 5](https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/5) on the `select` statement.

The code below has been edited with print statements to trace statements execution.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func fibonacci(c, quit chan int) {
    x, y := 0, 1
    fmt.Printf("Run fib with c: %v, quit: %v\n", c, quit)
    for {
        select {
        case c <- x:
            fmt.Println("Run case: c<-x")
            x, y = y, x+y
            fmt.Printf("x: %v, y: %v\n", x, y)
        case <-quit:
            fmt.Println("Run case: quit")
            fmt.Println("quit")
            return
        }
    }
}

func runForLoop(c, quit chan int) {
    fmt.Println("Run runForLoop()")
    
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        fmt.Printf("For loop with i: %v\n", i)
        fmt.Printf("Returned from c: %v\n", <-c)
    }
    
    quit <- 0
}

func main() {
    c := make(chan int)
    quit := make(chan int)
    go runForLoop(c, quit)
    fibonacci(c, quit)
}
```

The following is printed to the console.

```
Run fib with c: 0xc00005e060, quit: 0xc00005e0c0
Run runForLoop()
For loop with i: 0
Returned from c: 0 // question 1
For loop with i: 1
Run case: c<-x // question 2
x: 1, y: 1
Run case: c<-x // question 2
x: 1, y: 2
Returned from c: 1
For loop with i: 2
Returned from c: 1
For loop with i: 3
// ...
```

My questions are

- 1. The value of `c` is received here is `0` even though none of the select blocks have been executed. Could I confirm that this is the zero value of the `c` variable that has `int` type?
- 2. Why is case `c<-x` executed twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 1: It prints the result of `<-c`, which will block until another goroutine writes to it. So your statement is not correct: the select case for `c<-x` ran, with `x=0`. It is not the zero value of the chan variable. You will only read the zero-value of the chan type from a channel if the channel is closed, or if you use the two-value form of channel read: `value,ok := <-c`. When `ok=false`, `value` is the zero-value of the channel value type.

For 2: `c<-x` will execute 10 times, because you read from it 10 times in the for-loop, and only then you are writing to `quit`, which will enable the second case of the select. What you observe here is the second iteration of the loop.

Comment: Hi Burak, thanks for your response.

For 1: If the select case for c<-x ran for x=0, wouldn't "Run case: c<-x" be printed to the console before the "Returned from c: 0"?

Comment: For 2: I understand that c<-x will execute 10 times because of the for loop. I'm wondering why  the "Run case: c<-x" statements are printed out consecutively. I would expect one "Run case: c<-x" statement to be printed out when the case with x=0 ran.

Comment: @quattad - For 1: If the select case for c<-x ran for x=0, wouldn't "Run case: c<-x" be printed to the console before the "Returned from c: 0"?

This is not correct statement, since you have two threads of execution: one go routine runs runForLoop, and execution starts there, but blocks on a read from c. Then fibonacci function - executing on main thread - puts 0 to c, which "unblocks" runForLoop. Actual sequence of operations is not defined there, and is in discretion of go runtime

Comment: @quattad for 1: there are no execution ordering guarantees between two goroutines. Another goroutine can preempt the running one any time, in this case, it did before it can print the output

Comment: @quattad #2 is the same reason. When a goroutine writes to a channel, the other goroutine reads it and at that point, both goroutines are enabled. They can execute in any order.